# Opencart 301 Redirect error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, opencart

I read all availabe Q&A but i still did not found any solution.

I am running a Online store using wordpress.. now i move to opencart because of Payment Gateway option. but i have 301 URL redirect Problem..

http://website.com/2011/01/my-product-name/

to

http://website.com/my-product-name.html

My htaccess code:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   #### Rewrite Code ####
   RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
   Redirect 301 ^/2011/01/my-product-name/$ http://website.com/my-product-name.html
```

After when i try to redirect its redirect to

```
     http://website.com/my-product-name.html/?_route_=2011/01/my-product-name/
```

I don't know why its add ?*route*= inurl and all other other link?

is there any solution available?

Comment: i just found the solution..

I need to add ext ? question mark at the end of Redirect RULE like this..

      Redirect 301  /2010/10/my-product-name/ http://website.com/my-product-name.html?

Redirect perfectly work..


Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want a redirect rule for all of your 2011 products like that, you could use

```
RewriteRule ^/2011/\d{2}/([^/]+)/$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Assuming that

1. All your posts are to products
2. All of the posts are from 2011
3. You have set up url rewrites in OpenCart and assigned the last part
   (my-product-name) as the URL alias for each product

Of course, if some are articles, you could in fact rewrite to information pages with the same content as the old Wordpress posts using the same method as you have for products by giving them the correct url alias